# How do I join two tables in SAP ABAP based on two columns?

Tags: join, abap, opensql

I have two tables ACDOCA and BKPF. The two columns are GJAHR and BUKRS. I want to join these two tables based on these two columns. What will be the code for the select statement?

I did this:

```
 FROM acdoca AS a
   LEFT OUTER JOIN bkpf AS b
     ON a~rbukrs = b~bukrs
     ON a~gjahr = b~gjahr
```

Upon activating , it is showing the error, " "ON" is
invalid here (due to grammar). "

Please help.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

The second "ON" has to be replaced by "AND":

```
FROM acdoca AS a 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN bkpf AS b 
     ON a~rbukrs = b~bukrs AND " => here
        a~gjahr = b~gjahr
```

https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/de-DE/abapselect_join.htm#!ABAP_ONE_ADD@1@